# Counting non matching, shared digits between two numbers in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to figure out a way to determine the total number of non-matching, common digits between two numbers in python.

So far I can get the number of matching digits between the two numbers.The end goal is to have a function that takes two numbers ie 6621 and 6662 and return the numbers 2 for the number of matching digits and 1 for the number of non-matching shared digits.

I have tried using nested while loops to do this, but the count is not always accurate depending on the numbers being compared.

```
while i < n:#check 2. Nested while statements
    j = 0
    while j < n:

        if g_list[i] == p_list[j] and j == i:
            x
        elif g_list[i] == p_list[j]:
            z += 1
        print(g_list[i],p_list[j],z, i, j)
        j += 1

    i += 1
```

Comment: I probably should have included that lol. I have tried using recursion like this
  while i < n:#check 2. Nested while statements
           j = 0
           while j < n:
                
                if g_list[i] == p_list[j] and j == i:
                    x
                elif g_list[i] == p_list[j]:
                    z += 1
                print(g_list[i],p_list[j],z, i, j)
                j += 1
            
            i += 1
 Please excuse the poor formatting...

Comment: What would be your expected output for `66621` and `6662`?

Comment: I should also clarify, the digits will always be the same length.

Comment: In your example, isn't 6 also a matching digit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can count the number of occurrence of each digit in each number and take the minimum of those. This will get you the number of common digits, then you subtract the number of matching digits.

```
def get_count_of_digit(number):
    l = [0 for i in range(10)]
    list_digit = str(number)
    for d in list_digit:
        l[int(d)] += 1
    return l 

def number_of_common_digit(number1, number2):
    l1, l2 = [get_count_of_digit(n) for n in (number1, number2)]
    return sum([min(l1[i], l2[i]) for i in range(10)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do it this way:

```
a = 6661
b = 6662

def find_difference(first, second):
    first_list = list(str(first))
    second_list = list(str(second))
    c = set(first_list)
    d = set(second_list)
    print((len(c.symmetric_difference(d)),len(c.intersection(d))))
```

Output:

```
(2, 1)
```

Comment: For the problem I am trying to solve, the desired output for the values of 6661 and 6662 would be 3,0. The 3 being the matching 6's and the 0 being the non matching values. The solution above returns 3 for the values a = 6621 and b = 6298 where the desired output would be 1.

Comment: @doesitmatter ah, missed that part of your question. ill edit my answer shortly

Comment: @doesitmatter this is different from your original requirement..`The end goal is to have a function that takes two numbers ie 6621 and 6662 and return the numbers 2 for the number of matching digits and 1 for the number of non-matching shared digits.` - 6 and 2 are the matching digits and 1 is the non matching one. ill edit my answer to return (2,0)